# servicestack and razor in one project

Tags: servicestack

Did anyone try to have servicestack web service and razor page in one project using version 3.9.45, if yes,  is there anything different about latest version? I can get it to work in older version but not in 3.9.45.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug with the new Razor support that was [identified in this issue](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/issues/682) and fixed in v3.9.46+ of [ServiceStack.Razor](https://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Razor/).